# xamarin -keystore and apk have sha1 is different

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, apktool

I have old Xamarin android project. I made small changes and changed target to android x. The customer sent me a keystore file with password and alias. Now I need to sign and publish the package in google play. But I am getting the error your fingerprint does not match:

```
-need "Sha1Need"
-current "Sha1Other"
```

I check my key file with command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "my.keystore" -alias key -storepass mypass -keypass mypass
```

I get result value "Sha1Need".
Than I checking my apk with command:

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile my.apk
```

I get value "Sha1Other". How is it possible? And how can I fix this?

I use this code in my .csprj file:

```
 <AndroidSigningKeyStore>app.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
 <AndroidSigningStorePass>mypass</AndroidSigningStorePass>
 <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>alias</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
 <AndroidSigningKeyPass>mypass</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
```

**--UPDATED--**

This was a problem on the customer's side. He changed the password on the key several times, and one of the options worked.